# How to keep cursor position after calling ediff-current-file?

Tags: cursor, ediff

I would like to use ediff-current-file to jump to some of my previous changes/edits.  However, when I type 'q' to quit ediff after calling ediff-current-file and navigation (using 'p'/'n'), the cursor always jumps to the change near the end of the file.

Is it possible to stay at the line I chosen during ediff?

Comment: `GNU Emacs 25.1.50.2 (i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.8) of 2016-04-25` shows exactly your wanted behavior. Please retry with `emacs -Q`. If you get the wanted behavior with `emacs -Q` the unwanted behavior is caused by the system configuration or your configuration. You can test whether it is caused by the system configuration by [`emacs -q`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Initial-Options.html#index-_002d_002dno_002dinit_002dfile).

Comment: You are right!
I found that my setting about restore-window-configuration changed the behavior.
Thanks!

Comment: Please, answer your question and accept your answer. That marks this question as solved in the overview. Thanks in advance. Note, that you should not delete the question since the problem may happen to others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tobias mentioned, Emacs 25 shows exactly my wanted behavior.  I found that the problem comes from the following codes I copied from https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EdiffMode

```
(add-hook 'ediff-load-hook
         (lambda ()
               (add-hook 'ediff-before-setup-hook
                     (lambda ()
                       (setq ediff-saved-window-configuration (current-window-configuration))))
               (let ((restore-window-configuration
                  (lambda ()
                    (set-window-configuration ediff-saved-window-configuration))))
             (add-hook 'ediff-quit-hook restore-window-configuration 'append)
             (add-hook 'ediff-suspend-hook restore-window-configuration 'append))))
```

To fix it, I changed the last lambda function to:

```
(lambda ()
  (save-excursion
     (set-window-configuration ediff-saved-window-configuration))
  (recenter nil))
```